# Random scale and rotation within range and in circular shape (tree leaves)

Tags: mesh, particles, transforms

I'm doing some leaves meshes in ver 2.82 and want to know if there is a way to apply a scaling and rotation within a limited range so I won't have to do it on every leaves. I want to create some tuft just like this picture:

[image]

I'm trying to create a game with graphics in that style and want to keep it simple with low polygons.

I tried with particle system, but it not ended well lol. I really need more practices with this feature...

Maybe a ball with some leaf particles that use gravity so we can see the upper part of the leaves just like the pictures.

Comment: Hi. Please try to use existing tags when asking a question. Thanks.

Comment: could you be more specific? What exactly "didn't end well" when using a particle system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question lack precisions, but here is a try:

- Create your leaf object, here I've used a PNG picture with a transparent background. The following setup is very basic: it would need a bit of glossiness and translucency, and maybe random colors variations:

[image]

- Create the emitter. Here, to stick to the way the leaves emit, I've created a series of cylinders and cones:

[image]

- Give your object a *Particle System*. Choose *Hair*, enable *Advanced*, in *Emission* choose the *Number* of leaves you want to emit, enable *Rotation*, in *Render* choose *Render As > Object*, disable the *Show Emitter* option, and in *Instance Object* choose the leaf. Tweak with the various *Rotation* and *Scale* values.

[image]

- Your bush of leaves should show:

[image]

Comment: You understanded my question just right! this solution is perfect!